# menu toogle não voltando para media query desktop

Tags: jquery, css3

Estou desenvolvendo um menu responsivo e ele funciona normalmente, quando entra na media query para tablet ele esconde o menu e só é possível visualiza-lo através do click no botão, porém quando o menu está escondido e volto para resolução de desktop o menu continua escondido. No entanto se eu deixo o menu ativo na resolução de tablet e vou para desktop lá está o menu.

Exemplo do código :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('nav').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  list-style: none;
}
nav {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 40px;
}
ul {
  
}
li {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  color: black;
}
button {
  display: none !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  button {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadastre-se</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Menu Responsivo</button>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Tente utilizar fadeToggle no lugar de toggle

Comment: @MauroAlexandre continuou da mesma forma,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não se esqueça de incluir no head do html a tag meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

O menu é ativado / destivado com jQuery, por isso quando desativado em uma resolução menor, não voltará automaticamente para desktop *ao redimencionar a tela*.

Se quiser pode tentar algo assim:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     button {
         display: none;
     }
     nav {
         display: block;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sim, foi mais ou menos dessa forma que acabei resolvendo.